# Labelling Theorem Environments across documents

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

This might seem like a really obvious question to some of you but I am having a bit of trouble.

I use Theorem (and Lemma etc.) environments in my documents and reference them in the proof of others - pretty standard.

The trouble I am having is what to call my theorems - the ones without names anyway.

An obvious way is to number them the same way they appear in the document, but if I then go back and add or remove theorem environments this all goes kablooey.

Does anyone have a nice logical system for doing this?

**Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}


\begin{document}

\begin{lem}\label{lem2}
    This is the 1st lemma (2nd 'theorem') I write, but it clarifies the proof of the theorem below, so I place it above.
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
    The proof of lemma.
\end{proof}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
    This is the 1st theorem I write.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
    The proof of theorem using Lemma \ref{lem2}.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And do remember to use proper theorem constructions, not "homemade" ones.

Comment: Can you please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem referencing theorems? Such a MWE should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Theorems and lemmas always have a meaning, so you can give them logical names even if they are not named in the printed document. You should not use numbers for `\label`. But even if you do so, you don't need to change the `\label` if you reorder, add or delete something. If your editor does not assist in finding labels you can use a package like [`showkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys).

Comment: OTOH, remembering what you labeled theorem 3 could be more work than renaming them.  I've never found a better system, but boy can I use Replace All!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your problem is that you have some `\label`s in some document and want to refer to them using `\ref` in a separate (as in "compiled separately") document.

This is a job for the `xr` package:

> If one document needs to refer to sections of another, say `aaa.tex`, then this package may be loaded in the main file, and the command `\externaldocument{aaa}`
>   given in the preamble.
>   Then you may use `\ref` and `\pageref` to refer to anything which has been given a `\label` in either `aaa.tex` or the main document. You may declare any number of such external documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the theorems as per convenience and then label them using preassigned suitable names. For example, `\label{Continuity}`, `\label{date11.1.19}` etx

Comment: Better would be to use `\label{thm:Continuity}` etc.

Comment: Ya. That is better.